# Print all sequences of numbers using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

So I have this assignment in my computer algorithm class:
Write a recursive algorithm that, given a positive integer n >= 1, prints all
sequences of numbers
k >= 1 and 1 <= i1 < i2 <...< ik <= n.
For example: if n=3, then the output will be

1

1,2

1,2,3

1,3

2

2,3

3

I was trying to write the recursive code for this assignment in Java but I do not know how to approach this problem. I understand the basics of recursion but I have trouble writing recursive code by myself.

this is what I have right now:

```
public class question4
{  
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        int x = 10;
        printSequence(x);
    }
   public static int printSequence(int n){
       if (n == 1){
           System.out.println(n);
           return n;
       }
       else{
           int result = printSequence(n-1) + 1;
           System.out.println(result);
           return result;
       }
   }

}
```

It only prints 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show us the code you've got so far.

Comment: I think your teacher / professor / TA would be a better person to go to for help on this

Comment: Side note, good practice: classes name should be CamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start from the right most element and keep going to the left till you reach 1 (base case of recursion). At the base case, return "1".
Now start building the combinations bottom up. The function `foo` returns an array list of strings. At each level in the recursion, there are three parts. `Part1` is the array list returned by the previous call to `foo`;in `part2`, append `n` to all the elements returned by the previous call to `foo`; and finally in `part3`, append `n` to the array list.

```
import java.util.*;
class Sequence
{
    public static ArrayList<String> foo(int n)
    {
        if(n==1)
        {
            ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
            a.add("1");
            return a;
        }
        ArrayList<String> withOutN = foo(n-1);
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

        Iterator<String> it = withOutN.iterator();
        Integer i = new Integer(n);
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            String s = it.next();
            out.add(s);
            s = s.concat("," + i.toString());
            out.add(s);
        }
        out.add(i.toString());
        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n=4;
        ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

        out = (ArrayList<String>) foo(n);

        Iterator<String> it = out.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(( it.next()) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, having `n = 5` as example, you should print two kind of intervals

```
 1          | full interval
 1 2        |
 1 2 3      |
 1 2 3 4    |
 1 2 3 4 5  |

 1 _ 3 4 5  | concatenation of full interval (1 -> i) with (i+1 -> n)
 1 2 _ 4 5  |
 1 2 3 _ 5  |

 1 _ _ 4 5  | concatenation of full interval (1 -> i) with (i+2 -> n)
 1 2 _ _ 5  | 

 1 _ _ _ 5  | concatenation of full interval (1 -> i) with (i+3 -> n)
 ---------------------
   2        | full interval
   2 3      |
   2 3 4    |
   2 3 4 5  |

   2 _ 4 5  | concatenation of full interval (1 -> i) with (i+1 -> n)
   2 3 _ 5  |

   2 _ _ 5  | concatenation of full interval (1 -> i) with (i+2 -> n)
 ---------------------
     3      | full interval
     3 4    | 
     3 4 5  |

     3 _ 5  | concatenation of full interval (1 -> i) with (i+1 -> n)
 ---------------------
       4    | full interval
       4 5  |

         5  | concatenation of full interval (breaks here)
```

Then, what you have to do is:

1- print the full interval `from = 1` and `to = n`
2- iterate concatenating two intervals with "negative" parts
3- call again the recursive method passing `(from++, to)`

Hope it helps

Comment: There's a few cases that are being missed, i.e. 1, 2, 4, 5 from what I can tell. That's where things get messy.

Comment: @Compass you're right! The ignored numbers size in interval also need to be considered. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

From a set `{a, b, c, ...}`, you want `{a}` and `{}` joined with the set-of-all-subsets of `{b, c, ...}` recursively.